# GROUP BY with MAX date field - erratic results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Have a table containing form data.   Each row contains a `section_id` and `field_id`.   There are 50 distinct fields for each section.   As users update an existing field, a new row is inserted with an updated `date_modified`.  This keeps a rolling archive of changes.

The problem is that I'm getting erratic results when pulling the most recent set of fields to display on a page.

I've narrowed down the problem to a couple of fields, and have recreated a portion of the table in question on SQLFiddle.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cTable` (
  `section_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  KEY `section_id` (`section_id`),
  KEY `field_id` (`field_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[This query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cefd8/3) shows all previously edited rows for field_id 39.  There are five rows returned:

```
SELECT cT.* 
FROM cTable cT 
WHERE 
 cT.section_id = 123 AND
 cT.field_id=39;
```

Here's what I'm trying to do to pull [the most recent row](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cefd8/2) for `field_id` **39**.  No rows returned:

```
SELECT cT.* 
FROM cTable cT 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT field_id, MAX(date_modified) AS date_modified
  FROM cTable GROUP BY field_id
) AS max USING (field_id, date_modified)
WHERE 
 cT.section_id = 123 AND
 cT.field_id=39;

Record Count: 0;
```

If I try the same query on a different `field_id`, say **54**, [I get the correct result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cefd8/1):

```
SELECT cT.* 
FROM cTable cT 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT field_id, MAX(date_modified) AS date_modified
  FROM cTable GROUP BY field_id
) AS max USING (field_id, date_modified)
WHERE 
 cT.section_id = 123 AND
 cT.field_id=54;

Record Count: 1;
```

Why would same query work on one field_id, but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subquery from where you are getting maxima you need to `GROUP BY section_id,field_id` using just `GROUP BY field_id` is skipping the section id, on which you are applying filter

```
SELECT cT.* 
FROM cTable cT 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT section_id,field_id, MAX(date_modified) AS date_modified
  FROM cTable GROUP BY section_id,field_id
) AS max 
ON(max.field_id =cT.field_id 
   AND max.date_modified=cT.date_modified
 AND max.section_id=cT.section_id
  )
WHERE 
cT.section_id = 123 AND
 cT.field_id=39;
```

### [**See Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cefd8/15)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the max(date_modified) per field_id. But you should look for the max(date_modified) per field_id where the section_id is 123. Otherwise you may find a date for which you find no match later.

```
SELECT cT.* 
FROM cTable cT 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT field_id, MAX(date_modified) AS date_modified
  FROM cTable 
  WHERE section_id = 123 
  GROUP BY field_id
) AS max USING (field_id, date_modified)
WHERE 
 cT.section_id = 123 AND
 cT.field_id=39;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cefd8/19.